# Remove everything around a given pattern

Tags: vim, command-line

I have a text file with several columns separated by tabs, and thousands of lines like this:

```
Foo  Bar  foo@bar.com  01.01.0001  SomeMoreStuff
```

Now I would like to extract just the e-mail, which is `foo@bar.com` in this case.

What would the easiest way be to delete everything before and after the e-mail using `vim` or any other CLI tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command will print the third column:

```
cut -f3 file_name
```

Comment: I like this simple answer, especially because the standard delimiter is a tab, whereas the delimiter of `awk` is any space, if I read correctly.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this can be applied from within Vim using the filter feature: `:%!cut -f3`.

Answer (score 1):

using **awk**;

```
awk '$0=$3' file
```

using pure **vim**

try this line:

```
:%s/.*\t\([^@]\+@[^\t]\+\).*/\1/
```

if you are sure the email sits in the 3rd column, you could also try:

```
:%s/\v([^\t]*\t){2}([^\t]+).*/\2/
```

or using **vim + awk** if you like :)

```
:%!awk '$0=$3'
```

Answer (score 1):

For command line a simple awk will do the job:

```
awk '{print $3}' inFile
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vim I would escape the grim prospect of having to come up with a solid substitution by using a simple macro.

First, record the macro:

```
qq
0
d2f<tab> <-- this is a tab key
f<tab>   <-- this is a tab key
D
q
```

Second, apply the macro from the line below to the end of the buffer:

```
:+1,$norm @q
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash:

```
while read -a ARRAY; do echo ${ARRAY[2]}; done < input
```

perl in awk-mode

```
perl -lane 'print $F[2]' input
```